# Custom blogger domain gives "server not found" with fresh domain bought from GoDaddy

Tags: google, domains, godaddy, multiple-domains, blogger

I am trying to link my blog with one of the domain I bought on GoDaddy. Here is how I have linked it, is this correct? When I enter the blogger URL, I am properly redirected to custom domain, but then it says server not found. I bought the domain name around 4 hours back.

Config:
[image]

Comment: For reference, here are the instructions for setting up a custom domain from blogger: https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/55374?hl=en

Comment: Your `www` record does not look right.  According to the instructions it should point to ` <YOUR DOMAIN>.ghs.googlehosted.com` but you have it pointing to `ghs.google.com`

Comment: What is the purpose of the record that you blacked out?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller : I made that correction regarding ghs.google.com. That's a user specific blogger ID generated for my blog which I should add in the domains DNS management. Link : https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/1233387?visit_id=1-636383833960438962-3330886700&p=customdomain&hl=en&rd=2

Comment: Incase required, domain name is akshay.systems

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes ghs.google.com is also [correct one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfBQc.png). #WeareBorg please wait for some moment and then try to open your site link again on different browser or in incognito mode. Your system may still use the old address for that domain. Your setup look's all OK.

Comment: @Goyllo : So I don't need to add my custom domain name before ghs.google.com? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how blogger generate CNAME, but may be your blogusername.ghs.googlehosted.com and autoxyz.dv.googlehosted.com is work in same way. But here you already added auto generated CNAME, so you don't need to add second one. Right now just wait, or render your website on some online tool like pingdom or pagespeed insights. It's might already working on other machine.

Comment: @Goyllo : Yes, blogger was able to add the custom domain name means they were able to link it. Also, when I try looking for the ip-address, they are the ones provided by Google for A category.

Answer (score 1):

Site is live now, the settings were correct, it just took some time.